# Logarithmic equation 3^(x+1)+9^(x-1)-61236=0 produces unclear solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, quadratics

I have a basic logarithmic equation

```
3^(x+1) +9^(x-1) -61236 =0
```

which I simplified like

```
(x+1)*ln(3) + (2x-2)*ln(3) = ln(61236)
```

and furthermore

```
3x-1 = ln(61233)
```

If you solve for $x$ you get approximately $4.00748.$
If you enter the original equation into WolframAlpha the integer solution is $6.$
The WolframAlpha Link is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E%28x%2B1%29%2B9%5E%28x-1%29-61236%3D0).

Where is my mistake?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint. $3^{x+1}+9^{x-1}=3^{x+1}(1+3^{x-1})$

Comment: Take care $\log(a+b)\neq\log(a)+\log(b)$

Comment: I think you forgot a common factor $ln(3)$ by passing from the second to the third line

Comment: Hint: use exponentation rules and define $3^x=t$. Also, logarithm of sum is not sum of logarithms.

Comment: What I did in the second line(which is not written here) is factor out ln(3) and divide. So it's (x+1)+(2x-2) = ln(61236)/ln(3). Here the right side is ln(61236-3). Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You make a mistake when you take logarithms.

$\log a + \log b = \log ab$ and not $\log(a+b)=\log a+\log b$

Comment: OK, I see where my mistake is. But why is it mathematically wrong to transform 3^(x+1), 9^(x-1) and -61236 autonomously?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=3^x$. Then your equation can be written as
$$
61236=3^{x+1}+\frac{1}{9}9^x=3z+\frac{1}{9}z^2\iff z=-756\quad\text{or}\quad z=729.
$$
Is $z=-756$ admissible? What does $729=z=3^x$ imply about $x$?